# Use crypto.js with openssl

Tags: javascript, openssl, cryptojs

I'm trying to use crypto.js with openssl, so I would like to encrypt a message with one of them and decrypt with the other.

I included crypto.js from here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js

I tried in js:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("This is a message", "secret").toString()
```

The result is:

```
"U2FsdGVkX1+BK06UxXoEdF5CkAhhxRPAN5r+XYLse/PSgtWI5e9BX3pkMBRpF6Te"
```

Then with openssl I do:

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX1+BK06UxXoEdF5CkAhhxRPAN5r+XYLse/PSgtWI5e9BX3pkMBRpF6Te" | openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc -k "secret"
```

And I get this error:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
140411423139136:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
��+|�W��ۿ��4~
```

I also tried to add option -pbkdf2 to the openssl command, but I get a similar result.

And I also tried the other way like this:

```
echo "This is a message" | openssl enc -e -a -aes-256-cbc -k "secret" -pbkdf2
```

I get this result:

```
U2FsdGVkX1/QYJ+ZdUeun6mZn2aS+XxpnCTE3/50wc46Tvc3+JJxq+1rR3nS+4cP
```

Then in js I do:

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("U2FsdGVkX1/QYJ+ZdUeun6mZn2aS+XxpnCTE3/50wc46Tvc3+JJxq+1rR3nS+4cP", "secret").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

And I get:

```
""
```

I also tried to remove option -pbkdf2 in openssl command but I get the same result.

I spent hours on this problem, trying to change the algorithm, size key, etc. without finding any solution. Stack overflow is my last hope.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CryptoJS applies MD5 in its built-in key derivation. Note that OpenSSL uses MD5 as default digest in early versions and SHA256 since v1.1.0, i.e. in higher versions MD5 must be specified explicitly (`-md MD5`).

Comment: Oh it works ! I tried that but I didn't removed the -pbkdf2 option at this point so I thought it didn't help ^^'

Thank you very much !